# Xcode 8.2.1 UI builder and other tools in one window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8.2

When I click Main.storyboard in Xcode I get two windows. One is Xcode and the other is UI builder which is for me kinda messy. How can I have them as one window combined?

@ shallowThought @Steve Ives @Richard G Thanks guys for wanting to help. I spent to much time on trivial thing like this.

what i have

[image: what i have]

wanted:

[image: wanted:]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the two windows.

Comment: Cmd-Opt-Return (⌥⌘↩)

Comment: @vadian that is exactly what I wanted. Do you want to post it as a separate answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Actually it's the keyboard shortcut for the mouse click of Steve's answer (enable Assistant Editor).

Answer (score 0):

you can use tab (use command + T) or File -> New -> Tab. It opens a new tab and you can select whatever you want init.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the assistant editor enabled. You can turn it off using one of the butons in the top right-hand corner:

[image]